# No visible @Interface for 'UIAlertView' declares the selector

Tags: objective-c

The error is: "No visible @Interface for UIAlertview declares the selector 'initWithTitle:message:delegate:cancelButtonTitle:otherButtonTitle:'"

```
- (void) subtractTime;
{
     seconds --;
     timerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Time: %i", seconds];

     if(seconds == 0)
     {
         [timer invalidate];
         UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Time is up !"
                              message: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"You Scored %i points", count]
                              delegate:self
                              cancelButtonTitle: @"Play Again?"
                              otherButtonTitle:nil];
     }
}
@end
```

Comment: When you see that message and you know the method should be there, you should always look very carefully at your code: you've spelled the method name wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a typo in your code.

It should be:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Time is up !"
                                                message: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"You Scored %i points", count]
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle: @"Play Again?"
                                       otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

Note that it is "otherButtonTitles" but not "otherButtonTitle".

Comment: Thanks for that, unfortunately it hasn't fixed the primary error. I don't know what it means by, "no visible @Interface for UIAlertView"

Comment: @user2602189: No, this does address the error you're seeing. The message is telling you that the compiler can't find a method with that name in the class's header, which is usually caused by a typo. If you're still getting an error, you either didn't implement the fix correctly or you are now hitting a different error.

Comment: @user2602189 if you still see the error, maybe you have to manually import the UIKit header with `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>`. Please note that UIAlertView is typically only available on iOS. If you are developing for the Mac you won't be able to use it.